# how to set not to be logined in wp-admin except administrator?

Tags: wp-admin

My site has login page that anyone can login and register. So I want to protect wp-admin page that no one can enter this admin area except administrator. 
Is there a way to set that I want without plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: to customise WordPress, you need a plugin, whether a existing or one that you write yourself. then your question is not logical. edit your question to give more details about what you want and about the role of users that are denied to access backend.

Comment: Do you want people to be able to continue to log in and register? If you only want the admin to be able to log in and nobody else, you can use .htaccess to password-protect the login page and block everyone else from logging in or registering.

Comment: No, I want everybody to be able to login and register like now. I made custom login page using wordpress system. I just want to restrict to access to wp-admin except administrator.